# Boost template function multiple conditions

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I am trying to serialize data across a network and for the most part, templatization is paying off. I am having trouble with the following scenario.

```
template < typename type >
class SerializedVector
{
public:
   bool  SerializeIn( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset );
   bool  SerializeOut( U8* data, int& bufferOffset ) const;

   vector< type > m_data;
};
```

In the case of primitive types, serialization is simply a case of calling memcpy (htonl actually) but for std::string, I serialize the number of bytes, and then memcpy the buffer following. So I have one template function for primitive type and a specialization for std:string. Easy enough.

Now, I'd like to support classes serializing themselves in my m_data member... something like this:

```
struct TextEntry
{
   bool  SerializeIn( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset );
   bool  SerializeOut( U8* data, int& bufferOffset ) const;

   string   username;
   string   message;
};

class PacketTextHistoryResult : public BasePacket
{
public:
   PacketTextHistoryResult (){}

   bool  SerializeIn( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset );
   bool  SerializeOut( U8* data, int& bufferOffset ) const;

   SerializedVector< TextEntry > chat;
};
```

I've tried a lot of things but this is where I am stuck... any better ideas? This does not work.

```
template <typename type>
struct calls_member_serialize : boost::false_type { };

template <> 
struct calls_member_serialize< std::string > : boost::false_type { };

template <typename type> 
struct calls_member_serialize< boost::is_class< type > > : boost::true_type { };

template < typename type >
bool  SerializedVector< type >::SerializeIn( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset )
{
   int num = m_data.size();
   Serialize::In( data, bufferOffset, num );

   struct localScope
   {
      static void do_work( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset, type temp, boost::true_type const & )
      {
         temp.SerializeIn( data, bufferOffset );  <<<<<<<< See how I invoke the self-serialization here.
      }
      static void do_work( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset, type temp, boost::false_type const & )
      {
         Serialize::In( data, bufferOffset, temp ); // call the standard template function
      }
   };

   for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
   {
      type temp;
      localScope::do_work( data, bufferOffset, temp, ( calls_member_serialize< type >() ) ); //boost::is_fundamental<type>() || boost::is_class< std::string, type >()
      m_data.push_back( temp );
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your third `calls_member_serialize` does what you want it to do. Try this:

```
template <typename type>
struct calls_member_serialize :  boost::is_class< type >  { };

template <> 
struct calls_member_serialize< std::string > : boost::false_type { };
```

That way `calls_member_serialize<int>` derives from `boost::false_type` and `calls_member_serialize<TextEntry>` derives from `boost::true_type`.

A second problem you have is that `struct localScope` is not a template class so the compiler will try to instantiate both versions of the do_work function for each type causing a compiler error for types like `std::string`. You need to make your localScope helper class a template as well. However, template classes can't be at function scope, so it will look like this (untested):

```
namespace { // put in unnamed namespace to keep it local
   template<typename localType>
   struct localScope
   {
      static void do_work( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset, localType temp, boost::true_type const & )
      {
         temp.SerializeIn( data, bufferOffset );  
      }
      static void do_work( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset, localType temp, boost::false_type const & )
      {
         Serialize::In( data, bufferOffset, temp ); // call the standard template function
      }
   };
}

template < typename type >
bool  SerializedVector< type >::SerializeIn( const U8* data, int& bufferOffset )
{
   int num = m_data.size();
   Serialize::In( data, bufferOffset, num );

   for( int i=0; i<num; i++ )
   {
      type temp;
      localScope<type>::do_work( data, bufferOffset, temp, ( calls_member_serialize< type >() ) ); //boost::is_fundamental<type>() || boost::is_class< std::string, type >()
      m_data.push_back( temp );
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to setup the proper function calls after? I'd like to call the member function if it's a class, not a string class.